Why does higher price sensitivity cause a higher term premium in the yield curve?
I've read that ownership of the Treasury market has shifted from more price-insensitive ownership to more price sensitive ownership as the relative demand from the Fed, banks, and foreign investors has fallen. This will supposedly cause an increase in the term premium (steeper curve so longer dated bonds have higher yields and cheaper prices than short dated bonds). Why would this be the case? Is it because it would exacerbate the extent to which investors need cheaper prices to buy longer dated bonds? Or a different reason?
Thank you
